# How to parse JSON from Google Sheet using AngularJS app.factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-sheets, controller

I need your help. I tried everything and I couldn't find out how to do it. I have a code that reuses data from app.factory and now I want to update it from a Google Sheet:

I would like to know how to use my Google Sheet URL:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1UyzF5cxmxw1_WrpgUJ7t6hQMjXVslowpm0nZes1hn9E/2/public/full?alt=json

I have parsed it with:

But I want to avoid doing it every Controller I use, how do I put the parser and the creating of the right data parsed into app.factory just once?

I have tried several approaches without success, I am feeling a bit overwhelmed with it, can't think anymore.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Cheers,
Karla

// Today with normal structure

```
app.factory('DataTransfer', function($http) {
  var data = {};
  return {
    getPortfolioItems: function() {
      return $http.get('https://cupoom.club/json/cupoom.json');
    }
  };
});
```

// Today how I use inside several controllers

```
DataTransfer.getPortfolioItems().then(function(items) {
      $scope.portfolioList = items.data;
});
```

// How I use when code comes from Google Sheet but I need to put it inside app.factory

```
DataTransfer.getPortfolioItems().then(function(items) {
    var linha = items.data.feed.entry;
    var cupon = [];
    var categories_all = [];

    for (var i = 50; i < linha.length; i += 50){
        if (linha[i+3].content.$t !== "VAZIO") {

        cupon.push({
            id : linha[i+3].content.$t.toLowerCase(),
            name : linha[i+2].content.$t,
            description : linha[i+4].content.$t
        });

        }
    }

    console.log(cupon);
    $scope.portfolioList = cupon;   
});
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue of your script. And can I ask you about `tried several approaches` of `I have tried several approaches without success` and the detal of `without success` for each approaches?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your current issue. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. When I could correctly understand about your issue, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your script works for the data from `https://cupoom.club/json/cupoom.json`. When the URL is changed to the URL of your Spreadsheet, an error occurs. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike you made me keep thinking about it ;-)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way:

```
getPortfolioItems: function() {
    var cupoms = $http.get('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1UyzF5cxmxw1_WrpgUJ7t6hQMjXVslowpm0nZes1hn9E/2/public/full?alt=json')
    .then(function(items) {
        var linha = items.data.feed.entry;
        var cupon = [];

        for (var i = 50; i < linha.length; i += 50){
            if (linha[i+3].content.$t !== "VAZIO") {
                cupon.push({
                    id : linha[i+3].content.$t.toLowerCase(),
                    email : linha[i+1].content.$t,
                    description : linha[i+4].content.$t
                });
            }
        }
        return cupon;
        console.log(cupon);
    });
    console.log("1" + " // " + cupoms);
    return cupoms;
}};
});
```